# Webpack regex test for .js & .jsx

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack

I'm using webpack and wondering if there is a way to determine .js or .jsx file extensions with the test regex?

i.e.

```
test: /\.jsx?$/
```

Would this work?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/L3IgY2/1

Comment: yeah this is totally fine. surprised google didn't have this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes. `test: /.jsx?$/` should be the right way. But you also need to set `resolve.extensions` parameter to make it work.

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: why resolve? why we can't use a single regex for both `.js` and `.jsx` ?

Comment: You don't technically need to do this. With the above code you can now import a file w/o typing .jsx at the end like you already could with .js https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Answer (score 16):

i know this is very old question but i had like to share my solution.

solved it like this

```
test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
```

so, .js & .jsx or ts, tsx and mjs

these all extensions are going to be match. Much more elegant.
May it help someone.